# Rebol RebDB Relational Database: is there a better Syntax for inserting today's date

Tags: rebol

From User Guide http://www.dobeash.com/RebDB/db-guide.html

I did this

```
>> record: make block! []
== []
>> append record 'next
== [next]
>> append record now/date
== [next 13-Sep-2009]
>> append record "test insert date"
== [next 13-Sep-2009 "test insert date"]
>> db-insert my-table record
== [4 13-Sep-2009 "test insert date"]
>>
```

Any shorter way to do this in one line ?

Answer (score 1):

You could either use `COMPOSE`:

```
db-insert my-table compose [next (now/date) "test insert date"]
```

Or `REDUCE`:

```
db-insert my-table reduce ['next now/date "test insert date"]
```